# The nature of Bash's false

Tags: bash, shell

I saw something unexpected today.

```
$ bash -c 'false'
$ echo $?
1
```

This is as expected.

```
$ bash -c '[ false ]'
$ echo $?
0
```

Wat.

Similarly:

```
$ if [ false ]; then echo 'true'; fi 
true
```

I think I understand that `test` a.k.a. `[` does not execute its argument. But... what does it really **do** with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `test` (which is what `[` runs) does not run its argument, it evaluates it according to the operators it understands -- `!` `=` `!=` `-a` `-n` etc.  In particular, any string that doesn't match an operator is a test for not equal to the empty string.  `false` is such an unrecognized string, so it is compared against the empty string (not equal), so results in a `true` exit code...

`man test` will show you all of the operators `test` does understand.

Answer (score 4):

```
if { false ; } ; then echo TRUE; fi
if ( false ) ; then echo TRUE; fi
if false ; then echo TRUE; fi
```

All of these forms execute the false command.

```
if [ false ] ; then echo TRUE; fi
if test false ; then echo TRUE; fi
```

These don't execute anything.

Answer (score 1):

The `[` is a bash builtin command synonomous with the `test` builtin (which is different from `/usr/bin/test`). The most basic test is simply `[ string ]` which is true if string is not null or empty.

You can find extended examples [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#EX10).

Comment: So I don't actually need to use `[ -n $STRING ]` to test if `$STRING` is nonempty?

Comment: Correct.  The `-n` operator is for combining the empty string test with another test.  However, possibly empty strings cause lots of problems, so it's always [better to test guaranteed non-empty strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html#FTN.AEN3662):  `[ "x$string" != x -o "x$a" = "x$b" ]`

Comment: `[` is a binary too, hardlinked to `test` on OSX but separate on at least some Linux distros.

Answer (score 0):

`[` processes its arguments like any other program, it just happens to change its return value to more directly reflect what they contain. If you look in the man pages for it, you will see that when run with exactly two arguments (`false` and `]` in this case), it will exit with status code zero (true) if and only if the first is nonempty and the second is `]`.  Both are true, so it returns success.